# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoModulesCore.NativeModulesProxy.ExpoFirebaseCore') at expo sdk 42 in react native

Tags: expo, undefined

I am upgrading expo project from sdk 39 to sdk 44. While upgrading till sdk 41 I resolved issues by updating dependencies, packages used in project. After upgrading from sdk 41 to sdk 42 I resolved some issues but stuck there because I can't understand this error:

[image: image shows error occured on simulator]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my project as well, in my case as soon as I import FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal from expo-firebase-recaptcha.
so, I downgrade expo-firebase-recaptcha to 2.0.2 and it works.

I expect you are using the same in your project too, so you can try to run below in terminal to resolve this

```
yarn add expo-firebase-recaptcha@2.0.2
```

Hope this resolve your issue. if not, let me know in comment.